# Ember.Application.create with mixin and parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am creating an ember application using the Ember.Facebook mixin (https://github.com/luan/ember-facebook) which requires the Ember app to be defined as:

```
App = Ember.Application.create(Em.Facebook);
```

However, I need to define some parameters for my app, such as

```
{
rootElement: 'survey',
autoinit: false,
nextStep: 1,
appId: 113411778806173
}
```

Ideally these are added to the app using

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: 'survey',
  autoinit: false,
  nextStep: 1,
  appId: 113411778806173
});
```

so that they are there on runtime, however it is necessary to use App.setProperties() with the ember.facebook mixin.

How can I define the mixin and the parameters in the Em.Application.create() call?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In ember master, use:

```
App = Ember.Application.createWithMixins(Em.Facebook, {
  rootElement: 'survey',
  autoinit: false,
  nextStep: 1,
  appId: 113411778806173
});
```

In previous releases of ember, you can use `create` with the same syntax.

Comment: Could specify the versions? Which one are the previous releases? With which release was `createWithMixin` introduced?

Comment: `createWithMixins` was first released in 1.0.0-pre.3

Comment: Might I add here that it did not work for me until I did this: App.set("appId", id); right after the createWithMixin.

Comment: Note for people from the future like me:  [`createWithMixins` has been deprecated](https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-createwithmixins)