# Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super

Tags: ember.js

Why?

I've just built emberjs from the master branch (right now). I did not find any information about, why they have disabled support for _super...

Someone can make me smarter? :)

Answer (score 3):

A similar question was asked here:

[Ember.Application.create with mixin and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856755/ember-application-create-with-mixin-and-parameters)

If you use createWithMixin you will get the same functionality. A little more detail can be found with this commit in github:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/c1c720781c976f69fd4014ea50a1fee652286048