# Computed property returns a function? Not sure if me or a bug in the latest ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Hey y'all I'm having the weirdest issue in my ember code. (1.0-pre4)

This seemingly innocuous code is not working at all as expected:

```
a = Ember.Controller.create({ 
        hello: function(){ 
            return "hello"; 
        }.property() 
    } )
```

when I do `a.get("hello")` , instead of returning **hello**, it returns a function!

Here is a dump:

```
i
_cacheable: true
_dependentKeys: Array[0]
func: function (){ return "hello"; }
__proto__: Ember.Descriptor
```

In handlebars templates it shows up as **[object Object]**

I'm not by any means a seasoned Ember programmer.. but I am pretty sure this used to work differently. Has something changed?

However, I have noticed that when I call `a.hello.func()` then that returns **hello**!

This definitely doesn't make any sense. Could I be doing something wrong, or is there an issue with Ember??

Any help is appreciated. I know this question is similar to some others, but I have no other way to put down all my information in a cohesive fashion in the answers of the others.

Edit: I think I know what the issue is.. You can't specify computed properties in the 'create' function. Will try 'extend' first and report back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of ember 1.0.0-pre.3, you can no longer define computed properties via `Object.create()`. In most cases you should be using `extend`, but if you need the old behavior can use `createWithMixins()`.

See also:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/c1c720781c976f69fd4014ea50a1fee652286048

[Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976340/ember-object-create-no-longer-supports-defining-methods-that-call-super)

Comment: Oh! I see! That's a very useful thing to know. It seems that pre-4 doesn't throw any warnings though. I also just noticed the warning when I downgraded to pre-3.

Comment: If you're using ember-cli, then this error can be misleading. In my case, it meant that within my computed property I was referring to another computed property but forgot to access it via .get('propName'). Adding the get() accessor fixed the bug for me.