# Ember.js Upgrade to v1.0.0-pre.3 - Application initialize may only be called once

Tags: ember.js

When upgrading to v1.0.0-pre.3, I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super.
```

Which it appears that for performance reasons, the original create() functionality was preserved in createWithMixins()

Which is answered fairly clearly here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/c1c720781c976f69fd4014ea50a1fee652286048

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1623#issuecomment-11699639

[Ember.Application.create with mixin and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856755/ember-application-create-with-mixin-and-parameters)

But once I make that change, I now get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Application initialize may only be called once
```

A search of my codebase and I am only running an App.initialize() once.

```
(function(root){
  require(["config"], function(config){
    requirejs.config(config);
    require(["App", "domReady!", "ember"], function(App, doc, Ember){
        var app_name = config.app_name || "App";
        root[app_name] = App = Ember.Application.create(App);
        !App.isInitialized && App.initialize();
    });
  });
 })(this);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The callstack also shows a very suspicious : Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.initialize

Comment: Ember 1.0 pre4 is already out. And about your questions, read about [`Application#deferReadiness`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness)

Comment: Sorry, but Im not seeing what deferReadiness has to do with not having  to explicitly initialize the app anymore. Am I missing something?

Comment: Kind of. In early versions we'd normally use `initialize` when we had to load async stuff before booting the app, so the declaration would be `App = Em.Application.create({ autoinit: false'})`, then load a bunch of stuff into `App`, like a extension library for example, and when that's done you'd call `initialize`, but now `deferReadiness` is how we tell the framework to wait until we load some stuff, and `advanceReadiness` makes it boot the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't need to call initialize at all with the new version.